# DataGrid's DataGridComboBoxColumn binding to Dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I am new to WPF and I try to get the DataGrid's DataGridComboBoxColumn right setting up the bindings.

I have a Dictionary of possible elements for the combobox column, the Key is the Id that the item property should have and the Value is the text to be shown in the ComboBox. The Dictionary look like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> users;
```

and a List of items that populates the DataGrid, each item with an Id value for the combobox:

```
public static List<FileItem> fileItems = new List<FileItem>();

//...

public class FileItem {
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

The XAML looks like this right now:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridUpdates" Margin="12,74,10,313" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding FileItems}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn  x:Name="ClmOwner" Header="Owner" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"  SelectedValueBinding="{x:Null}" SelectedItemBinding="{x:Null}" TextBinding="{x:Null}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I tried with:

```
SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=OwnerId}" SelectedValuePath="OwnerId"
```

but didn't work, the rows are shown with the empty ComboBox since it has no ItemsSource because I don't know where to set it.

In the code-behind I can set the ItemsSource like this to set at least the list of values:

```
ClmOwner.ItemsSource = FileItem.users;
```

but I would prefer using XAML.

The question is how do I set the XAML bindings for the ComboBox to get the values of the users Dictionary, and have the value selected to that of the OwnerId property.

PS: Im not sure either if the DataContext should be as it is now with the value "{Binding FileItems}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> xaml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridUpdates" Margin="12,74,10,313" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding FileItems}" 
              SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedOwnerId, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedValuePath="Key"
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn  x:Name="ClmOwner" Header="Owner"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyViewModel.Users}, Mode=OneWay}"   DisplayMemberPath="Value"
                   SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ComboSelectedItem}"
                   />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

> xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static Dictionary<int, string> users;
    //Lets say this is ur static dictionary
    public static Dictionary<int, string> Users
    {
        get
        {
            return users ?? (users = new Dictionary<int, string> { 
            {1,"User1"},
            {2,"User2"},
            {3,"User3"}
            });
        }
    }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        //Fill the collection
        FileItems = new ObservableCollection<FileItem>
            {
            new FileItem{OwnerId=1},
            new FileItem{OwnerId=2},
            new FileItem{OwnerId=3},
            };

    }

    //This will be binded to the ItemSource of DataGrid
    public ObservableCollection<FileItem> FileItems { get; set; }

    //Selected Owner Id . Notify if TwoMode binding required
    int selectedOwnerId;
    public int SelectedOwnerId
    {
        get
        { return selectedOwnerId; }
        set { selectedOwnerId = value; Notify("SelectedOwnerId"); }
    }

    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

> FileItem

```
public class FileItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int ownerId;
    public int OwnerId
    {
        get
        { return ownerId; }
        set { ownerId = value; Notify("OwnerId"); }
    }

    KeyValuePair<int, string> comboSelectedItem;
    //This will have ComboBox Selected Item If SO need it 
    public KeyValuePair<int, string> ComboSelectedItem
    {
        get { return comboSelectedItem; }
        set { comboSelectedItem = value; Notify("ComboSelectedItem"); }
    }

    //.... other properties
    //.....

    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `DataGridComboBoxColumn` needs to bind to the dictionary. This means you need to set the `ItemsSource` to it. Once you do this, your `DisplayMemberPath` will likely be your Dictionary item's `Value` and SelectedValuePath with be your Dictionary item's `Key`. `Dictionary` internally stores everything as a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` which has `Key` and `Value` properties.

Bind the `ItemSource` to an instance of your dictionary and try:

```
SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"
```

Comment: Thank you, those two xaml attributes are right what I needed, if I set the ItemsSource in the code-behind that would be all.

Answer (score 0):

I also add that "Key" and "Value" are case sensitive.
In my code,

```
SelectedValuePath="key"
```

Doesn't work, the combobox shows empty items even if there as many as the dictionary length.